# Why do we always see this number 32767px in css file

Tags: css, browser, opera

Is that used for do tricky thing in opera, I know that opera browser has a limitation that element cannot be wider than 32767px.

Is this number a standard? (I don't think so)

What about other browsers? like chrome firefox IE, do they have the same kind of limitation?

Thanks,

Comment: Other browsers have a limit of 2^31-1, as do recent versions of Opera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Some people will immediatly notice the 32,767 as the programatic max
>   value for an ‘Integer’, which is exactly what the problem is. Opera
>   for some reason, and it is completly alone here, as all other browsers
>   even the dreaded Internet Explorer 6, can handle CSS values that
>   exceed this limit. Opera will silently fail, throw no warning about it
>   and ignore all styles that follow non integer numbers in your
>   selector.
>
> There was no way around this I could find to make it work in Opera,
>   simply put.
>
> Any number bigger then 32,767 for a value in CSS when displaying with
>   Opera 10, will be ignored and cause all following styles in that
>   selector to be dropped.

http://www.aplusdesign.com.au/blog/opera-css-integer-bug/

So, in short, no, it shouldn't affect other browsers. It is "standard" as in it relates to integer max value. It is the highest number that can be represented in a signed 16-bit integer (to be exact, the range is 2^15-1 to -2^15 or 32767 to -32768).

Edit: however, there have been few bugs in other browsers too related to the same max value, such as [iframe size limit bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=333994) in Firefox, so things related to the same number might pop up in some other context with other browsers too. But CSS value bug should be Opera-only.

Edit2: webinista pointed out in the comments that the Opera behaviour should be fixed from version 11.60 onwards and this magical number should not be needed after that.

Comment: so people use the value to do tricky things in 16-bit coordination screen. ah, that seems hack on css in some way.

Comment: Per-spec it's not a bug — CSS doesn't define what the valid range is.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in Opera 11.6x.

Comment: @gsnedders: I would still consider silently failing a bug - even if the limit were by design, I don't think it can reasonably be argued that it should work the way described